# .net core app somehow prompted for password when there are more users

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I built .net core web application using windows authentication. It works nicely at the development or production environment with a few users. However when the app was installed and test on the production environment with more users(20 users) users are been kicked out and prompted for users all the time. I am not sure why this is happening. On IIS concurrent connection is set to 4294967295 as default the same setting for mssql is 32767. What else could be wrong. Is there any monitor tools or applications to find out what is the problem? IIS is 8 and windows2012 is for server.

Comment: how does your application store its sessions? Perhaps it is running out of session storage space or not configured to store more than 20 sessions at once...

Comment: Good point but I have tested with 20 or more users in local machine with JMeter and it works.